# FFmpeg sample_fmt not actually changing bit _depth + missing supported sample formats

Tags: ffmpeg

**Disclaimer: I am a beginner about all of this, this question might be stupid**

I am attempting to change a mp3 files bit depth from 32 to 16 and also changing the  bitrate

This is my command:
`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -sample_fmt s16p -vsync 2 -b:a 256k output2.mp3`
The bitrate changes successfully but the bit depth doesn't.

These  are  the  results.

**Input file:**
`ffprobe -i input.mp3`

```
Duration: 00:04:40.08, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 323 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
```

**Output file:**
`ffprobe -i output.mp3`

```
Duration: 00:04:40.08, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 283 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
```

Or  in another way this  is  what  VLC's media codec  gives me :
[CurrentMediaInformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsUFq.png)

We can see fltp which I believe after a google search means 32 bit

Now this is  using **s16p** but if  I try **s16** I get the following:

```
[libmp3lame @ 000001645fdcaec0] Specified sample format s16 is not supported by the libmp3lame encoder
[libmp3lame @ 000001645fdcaec0] Supported sample formats:
[libmp3lame @ 000001645fdcaec0]   s32p
[libmp3lame @ 000001645fdcaec0]   fltp
[libmp3lame @ 000001645fdcaec0]   s16p
```

Interesting, because If I type `ffmpeg -sample_fmts` I  get this:

```
name   depth
u8        8
s16      16
s32      32
flt      32
dbl      64
u8p       8
s16p     16
s32p     32
fltp     32
dblp     64
s64      64
s64p     64
```

Which seems to mean s16  should  work  no?
Am  I  completely missing  something here?
What  is  going  on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compressed data in a MP3 file is coded so it does not have any inherent storage format or bit depth. The `Supported sample formats` refers to the sample formats that the encoder accepts for processing.

The sample format shown for output.mp3 is what the decoder emits. By default, ffmpeg uses the mp3float decoder which outputs single-precision floating point samples. To get 16 bit integer, force the mp3 fixed point decoder,

```
ffmpeg -c:a mp3 -i output.mp3
```

(ffprobe does not support custom decoder specification)